Meaning of the borrowing "programé" (found as a noun in English, but an adjective in French)
As most often is the case, when a word with a French form, but used as English vocabulary, is the object of a Google search in the English corpus, the result is a series of hits strictly out of the French corpus, which might be some help, although  in rare cases, and can't ever lead to anything conclusive. I don't understand how that can be, but one more time this happened today as I tried to get some information on a word.
The word I am looking for is found in a very short  critical study in which there are two occurrences of it. It is not in The Shorter Oxford English Dictionary, nor in any Web dictionaries, and thus appears to be a recent borrowing (to which a particular sense has been given, that is, a sense that  has probably very little to do with any of the French meanings).
It is the word "programé", in the 2021 paper "De Profundis: an Elision of the “I” Through its Presence", by Aaron Graham (UNCG). The two sentences follow.


Wilde’s observations in De Profundis do not flow from the excess of epicurean
pleasure and commitment to performativity that characterize his artistic and critical programé or philosophy of life.

This approach to art—or really to life itself—stands in diametric opposition to the programé embarked upon by the younger, yet-to-be-indicted Oscar Wilde.



Evidently enough, "artistic and critical programé" points directly to "philosophy of life", but what are the implications that  the term "programé" enfolds, by itself? In other words what would be a  definition of this word? It is clear it has nothing to do with the word "programme" as found in the fields of television and information technology.
Correction
This term might come Spanish: the correction in the Google search yields this page of results.

I'd guess it means the same as "program 3: a plan or system under which action may be taken toward a goal" but without access to the paper (I'm not registering with a random site) it's hard to be sure. (Or know why the French was used; maybe it's used in a text Graham cites; maybe it's an error.)

I'm wondering if it's an attempt merely to code for the French pronunciation. Pro gramme.  [sorry; can't avoid the unwanted space] Do the French have a sense not really covered by the usual English definitions? This would make this a nonce usage, not on-topic.

@StuartF One m, but in French there are two. I made the correction.

@EdwinAshworth There is such a sense, in "enseignement programmé", which concerns a method for teaching pupils according to their ability to assimilate, but the English meaning has certainly nothing to do with that. I suspect there is at the root the basic idea that "programme" or English "program" confers, but I can't figure out any genuinely inspiring French idea behind this coinage.

There is another ambiguity in this search, as the word "programé" (one m) would be issued from Spanish. This is shown by the correction in the ngram search, which this time is mostly in the Spanish corpus.

It wouldn't be the first time an anglophone academic has shown an embarrassing lack of skill at a foreign language. But maybe there is more to it.

It doesn’t appear in The Oxford Dictionary of Literary Terms, either the third or fourth edition.

Has anyone tried looking for ' programmé' / ' programé' in the OED? I can't find it there, but I haven't got full access. It's not in Wiktionary or Britannica Dictionary. This seems a protologistic usage. It needs scare-quotes and an in-line definition.

Wait, where did the wacky accent aigu come from? My understanding is that there is the French noun programme, as well as the verb programmer, and that such accents normally indicate a participle. Which... as you observe, makes no sense in these English sentences. Maybe it's just a gesture to make it seem more "Frenchy"?

Yes to Andy's comment. Either that or just a mistake/typo.

Have you encountered this anywhere other than in Aaron Graham's writing on Wilde? (Does it show up in Wilde himself?) I don't want to cast aspersions, as the surrounding material seems eloquent and insightful—AND my own doctorate is from the same university—but I think I might spot a few possible typos like "Wilde's per-prison life."

@AndyBonner This is the first time I read this word, and it seems to me that the repetition of it (as the same part of speech) makes it difficult to believe the author could not quite know what is meant by it.  I  found the term "per-prison life" to be an obstacle, and I have not yet understood what this construction is. I also found some comma problems (I am not sure I agree with some cases of use and nonuse); however that did not drive me to  suspect at all the author as a careless user of words.

@LPH I take “per-prison” to be “pre-prison”

@AndyBonner It is common practice to turn adjectives into nouns in French ("programmé" is both an adjective and a past participle), and this word is used twice as a noun of the English language.

@AndyBonner A question quickly resolved! Thnk you.
